# No sound from headphones suddenly, although it is recognized

Tags: 14.04, sound, headphones

My headphones were working fine, but recently stopped working, though they are still recognized.

The headphones work perfectly on any other device.

I've searched on the internet, but wasn't able to find a solution.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 on an ASUS k46cb.

Comment: Make sure that in your 'sound settings' it's pointing to the proper device. For example, my desktop has a sound device for HDMI that sometimes gets chosen by default when one of the other sources disappear.

Comment: @musher yes I've already checked that, it's right. I also checked alsamixer and everything seems fine